# Update values in React/NodeJS MySQL query using previous values if nothing entered

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am using React and NodeJS to make a front end to my MySQL workbench data for mock blood donation management system. I would like to make it that when a user updates their contact information, they only have to fill out the information they are updating and not all the columns.

The GUI looks like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaWXL.png

Currently my UPDATE statement looks like this:

```
    app.put("/api/update/:log_ID", (req, res) => {
    const ID = req.params.log_ID;
    const SSN = req.body.SSN;
    const Name = req.body.Name;
    const Phone = req.body.Phone;
    const City = req.body.City;
    const State = req.body.State;
    const BloodType = req.body.BloodType;
    const DonationType = req.body.DonationType;
    const LastDonationDate = req.body.LastDonationDate;
    const LastDonationType = req.body.LastDonationType;

    const sqlUpdate =
        'UPDATE `donor` SET SSN = ?, \
        Name = ?, \
        Phone = ?, \
        City = ?, \
        State_Abbr = ?, \
        Blood_Type = ?, \
        Donation_Type_ID = ?, \
        Last_Donation_Date = ?, \
        Last_Donation_Type = ? \
        WHERE log_ID = ? ';
    
    db.query(sqlUpdate, [SSN, Name, Phone, City, State, BloodType, DonationType, LastDonationDate, LastDonationType, ID], (err, result) =>{
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(result);
        
    })
});
```

I have tried using the format coalesce(@Name, ?) or coalesce(Name, ?) for each one and it worked for a few of them but started to bug out when it got to the Donation_Type_ID because it couldn't retrieve the previous value so I am back to square one. TIA

Comment: Can you please describe what do you want to do with formating coalesce ? and what is back to square one?

Comment: I am formatting each const in the query so it looks like  SSN = coalesce(SSN, ?), Name = coalesce(Name, ?). This got me so far as only needing to fill in half the fields instead of all of the fields when I wanted to update. I want to only be able to fill in the things I need for my update, not every field. Square one is I need to fill in every field instead of just the ones I need (With MySQL filling in the previous values for the fields not filled)